# How to convert RealmResults object to RealmList?

Tags: android, realm

I have a `RealmResults <Student>` object. I want to convert it to `RealmList <Student>` object. any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
RealmList <Student> results = new RealmList<Student>();

results.addAll(realmResultList.subList(0, realmResultList.size()));
```

Comment: I will accept it for now until I get a better answer

Comment: Shouldn't `realmResultList.size()` be `realmResultList.size() - 1`?

Answer (score 13):

Please try and let me know if this work for you.

```
RealmList <Student> finalList = new RealmList<Student>();

finalList.addAll(yourRealmResults.subList(0, yourRealmResults.size()));
```

Comment: is it `.size()` or `.size()-1`?

Comment: `.size()` the second parameter is the length, not the position.

Comment: @Ralphilius isn't it `toIndex`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-

Answer (score 13):

Since 0.87.0

> - Added Realm.copyFromRealm() for creating detached copies of Realm objects (#931).

Which allow just return list `List<E extends RealmObject>`

Answer (score 9):

`RealmResults` implements the `List` interface and so does the `RealmList`.

```
RealmList <Student> results = new RealmList<Student>();
results.addAll(realmResultsList);
```

Answer (score 3):

In new update you can use **copyFromRealm** method to do so :

```
RealmList<Student> finalList = realm.copyFromRealm(resultsAnswers);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the elements of this `RealmList` will be unmanaged, which means they cannot be set for realm objects as a list value in write transaction.

Comment: Get them from a managed object, don't get them with `new RealmList<>()`.

Answer (score 3):

**RealmResults** is returned if a query is expected to give a collection of objects *(e.g. `RealmQuery<E>.findAll()`)*. Otherwise, single object queries will return a **RealmObject**.

**Managed and Unmanaged Objects**
`RealmResults` are **managed** objects, meaning they cannot be manipulated outside of Realm transactions and are confined in the thread that created them. Converting `RealmResults` into a `RealmList` will make the data **unmanaged**, as what @epicpandaforce pointed out, meaning the objects in the list are not connected to the database anymore and are basically normal Java objects which can be transferred in between threads and manipulated.

To convert `RealmResults` to a `RealmList`:

```
RealmResults<User> results = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
RealmList<Users> users = realm.copyFromRealm(results);
```

Changes to an unmanaged object will not in any means affect the original in the database unless a `realm.copyToRealm(users)`, doing the opposite of `copyFromRealm()`, is executed after. Keep in mind that `RealmLists` can be managed or unmanaged, as a `RealmObject` from a `RealmResult` can have the following structure in which the `RealmList` in this case is a managed object:

```
class User {
  int               id;
  String            name;
  RealmList<String> petNames;
}
```

Finally, `copyFromRealm()` returns a `List` so it's also possible to do

```
ArrayList<User> users = realm.copyFromRealm(results);
```

Answer (score 2):

Realm has some new features check-in documentation
[Realm Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/)

Realm has copyfromRealm function which we can use to convert the result to list

```
RealmList<Student> student=realm.copyfromRealm(Realmresult);
```

Answer (score 0):

@JemshitIskenderov This should copy for you.

```
public RealmList<Student> convertResultToList(RealmResult<Student> realResultsList){
    RealmList <Student> results = new RealmList<Student>();

    for(Student student : realResultsList){
       results.add(copy(student));
    }
}

private Student copy(Student student){
    Student o = new Student();

    o.setCreated(student.getCreated());
    o.setModified(student.getModified());
    o.setDeleted(student.getDeleted());
    o.setName(student.getName());
    //List more properties here
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Code:***

```
public class RealmCollectionHelper {

     public static <C extends RealmModel> RealmList<C> mapperCollectionToRealmList(Collection<C> objects){
         if (objects == null){
             return null;
         }
         RealmList<C> realmList = new RealmList<>();
         realmList.addAll(objects);

         return realmList;
     }
}
```

Here my gist: https://gist.github.com/jmperezra/9b4708051eaa2686c83ebf76066071ff

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of doing it:

```
RealmList<YourClass> dummy = new RealmList<>();
Iterator<YourClass> it = realmResultsList.listIterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
      dummy.add(it.next());
}
```